# KendoUI Chart export using MemoryStream

Tags: kendo-ui, kendo-asp.net-mvc, inkscape

I found this helpful repo on github, its a kendoui example using Inkscape to output an svg as either an pdf or png by posting the data from the chart to the mvc controller.

[Github repo](https://github.com/telerik/kendo-examples-asp-net/blob/master/chart-inkscape-export/Controllers/HomeController.cs)

It creates a temporary svg file and png within the App_Data folder which is fine if you your happy with the files being left there.

The main goodness happens in this piece of code

```
 private string DoExport(string svgFile, ExportFormat format)
    {
        var extension = format == ExportFormat.PNG ? "png" : "pdf";
        var outFile = TempFileName() + "." + extension;

        // Full list of export options is available at
        // http://tavmjong.free.fr/INKSCAPE/MANUAL/html/CommandLine-Export.html
        var inkscape = new Process();
        inkscape.StartInfo.FileName = INKSCAPE_PATH;
        inkscape.StartInfo.Arguments =
            String.Format("--file \"{0}\" --export-{1} \"{2}\" --export-width {3} --export-height {4}",
                          svgFile, extension, outFile, WIDTH, HEIGHT);
        inkscape.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = true;
        inkscape.Start();

        inkscape.WaitForExit();

        return outFile;
    }
```

After  `inkscape.Start();` runs the png file is created within the `app_data` folder and `outFile` (the path to the app_data image) is returned from the method.

Instead of creating the file is it possible to do everything in memory and return the image with the actionresult?

```
[HttpPost]
    public ActionResult _Export(string svg, ExportFormat format)
    {
        var svgText = HttpUtility.UrlDecode(svg);
        var svgFile = TempFileName() + ".svg";
        System.IO.File.WriteAllText(svgFile, svgText);

        var outFile = DoExport(svgFile, format);
        var attachment = "export" + Path.GetExtension(outFile);

        return File(outFile, MimeTypes[format], attachment);
    }
```

I am not sure how to do this and if it can be done.